# Close mongo / mongolian connection right after opening it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Can't close connection right after opening it tried both db.server.close() and server.close()

```
var Mongolian = require("mongolian");
var server = new Mongolian;
var db = server.db("database");
var shops = db.collection("collection");
db.server.close();
server.close();
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Mongolian = require("mongolian");
var server = new Mongolian();
var database = server.db("database")
var db = {
    collection: database.collection("collection"),
};

db.collection.find({},{"id":1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, array){
    console.log(array);
    server.close();
});
```

You can't close mongo until you make a request, then `server.close()` will work.